# SQL Granting create table permissions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

I am trying to grant a newly created user the ability to create tables.

I would have thought it would be

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE ON databaseName.* TO userName_3;
```

However, I receive a syntax error while trying to execute this SQL statement.

Would anyone be able to tell me why it is not working?
Thanks

Comment: What is the syntax error

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table to userName_3' at line 1

Comment: What SQL product are you using? Please [edit] and add an appropriate tag (as was suggested when you added the [tag:sql] tag). Syntax may vary between products.

Comment: Server version: 5.7.17-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this
[SQL Server grand permission](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/sql-server-granting-permissions-to-an-entire-schema-vs-object)

```
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA :: databaseName TO userName_3;
```

For [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

```
GRANT CREATE ON databaseName.* TO userName_3;
```

You can't use the `TABLE` in the query

> > Table Privileges
>
> Table privileges apply to all columns in a given table. To assign
>   table-level privileges, use ON db_name.tbl_name syntax:
>
> GRANT ALL ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost'; GRANT SELECT, INSERT
>   ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost'; If you specify tbl_name rather
>   than db_name.tbl_name, the statement applies to tbl_name in the
>   default database. An error occurs if there is no default database.
>
> The permissible priv_type values at the table level are ALTER, CREATE
>   VIEW, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, GRANT OPTION, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES,
>   SELECT, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER, and UPDATE.
>
> Table-level privileges apply to base tables and views. They do not
>   apply to tables created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, even if the table
>   names match. For information about TEMPORARY table privileges, see
>   Section 13.1.18.3, “CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Syntax”.
>
> MySQL stores table privileges in the mysql.tables_priv table.